# T SQL: Select each matched row as column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL Server and have a problem

Here is my baseline situation:

Table foo:

```
id | pid  | val1 | val2 | val3
------------------------------
1  | 4721 |  1   |  2   |  3
2  |   25 |  4   |  5   |  6
3  | 4721 |  7   |  8   |  9
```

Result table:

```
pid | id_1 | val1_1 | val2_1 | val3_1 | id_2 | val1_2 | val2_2 | val3_2 | id_3 | val1_3 | val2_3 | val3_3
----------------------------------------------------
4721 | 1  |  1   |  2   |  3  | 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 3 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

What I want is to select all matched rows to pid = 4721, and show them in a separate column.

Comment: why is second row in result?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri sry, the second row is wrong at the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the SQL answer to this problem is, "This is a display issue.  Display is an application problem, not a database problem."  Relationally speaking, this is also asking the server to break First Normal Form and create repeating groups, meaning it's almost certainly going to require jumping through a few hoops and will have significant limitations.

The "right way" according to a DBA would be doing something like:

```
SELECT pid, id, val1, val2, val3
FROM Table
ORDER BY pid, id;
```

Then, in your application, walk through your result set and format the output as you need it.

You could even include an order for each `id` within the `pid` to maybe make it a bit easier:

```
SELECT pid, 
    id, 
    val1, 
    val2, 
    val3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pid, ORDER BY id) AS "id_order"
FROM Table
ORDER BY pid, id;
```

**However, let's say you can't do that.**

If you absolutely *have* to do this with SQL (e.g., your reporting software doesn't handle this kind of thing and it's all you've got) and you know you never have more than 3 `id` for each `pid`, you can try something like this:

```
;WITH Table_id_ordered AS (
    SELECT pid, 
        id, 
        val1, 
        val2, 
        val3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pid, ORDER BY id) AS "id_order"
    FROM Table
)
SELECT t1.pid,
    t1.id   as id_1,
    t1.val1 as val1_1,
    t1.val2 as val2_1,
    t1.val3 as val3_1,
    t2.id   as id_2,
    t2.val1 as val1_2,
    t2.val2 as val2_2,
    t2.val3 as val3_2,
    t3.id   as id_3,
    t3.val1 as val1_3,
    t3.val2 as val2_3,
    t3.val3 as val3_3
FROM Table_id_ordered t1
LEFT JOIN Table_id_ordered t2
    ON t2.pid = t1.pid
    AND t2.id_order = t1.id_order + 1
LEFT JOIN Table_id_ordered t3
    ON t3.pid = t2.pid
    AND t3.id_order = t2.id_order + 1
WHERE t1.id_order = 1;
```

Obviously, that's only good for up to three `id` for any `pid`,.  As written, it also won't tell you if there's an `id` in your table that would be in a fouth or fifth.  They're just completely absent from the results.  The first method I mentioned will always return all the data, and the application can be written to handle that pretty easily.

Dynamic solutions can be created to do this for any number of `id`s for a `pid`, but those are significantly more complicated.

Comment: thanks a lot, you realy helped me. i will organize the output on the application side, but this is an another topic.

Answer (score 0):

I first Unpivot your data to get your list of columns and values, assign the new column names, then dynamically pivot your data. This should work for any combination of values.

**Note:** I slightly changed the column names so they would sort properly.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #yourTable;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UnpivotTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #UnpivotTable;

SELECT * INTO #yourTable
FROM
(
    SELECT 1,4721,1,2,3
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2,25,4,5,6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,4721,7,8,9
) AS  bar(id,pID,val1,val2,val3);

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT  pID,
        --This is where I create the column names
        CONCAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pID,col ORDER BY pID,id2),'_',col) NewColName,
        val INTO #UnpivotTable
FROM 
(
    --I need ID2 for ROW_NUMBER() so the NewColNames are applied to the correct values
    SELECT *,id as ID2
    FROM #yourTable
) A
UNPIVOT
(
    val FOR col IN(ID,val1,val2,val3)
) unpvt


--Puts columns in alphabetic order into @cols
SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(NewColName)
FROM #UnpivotTable
--Group by gets rid of any duplicate column names
GROUP BY NewColName
ORDER BY NewColName

EXEC
(
    'SELECT *
    FROM #UnpivotTable
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(val) FOR newColName IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) pvt
    WHERE pID = 4721'
)

--Cleanup
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #yourTable;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UnpivotTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #UnpivotTable;
```

Results:

```
pID         1_id        1_val1      1_val2      1_val3      2_id        2_val1      2_val2      2_val3
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
4721        1           1           2           3           3           7           8           9
```